# OpenXML in C# .NET Core

Tags: c#, excel, .net-core, openxml

Saving the filestream of an uploaded file to "var"

```
var fileStream = new MemoryStream(fileModel.FileData);
using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(fileStream))
{
    _ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
```

ExcelPackage "package" variable is not storing the file's memory stream data.
This is happening only for one Excel file. Copying the data from this excel to a different one, I am able to upload it and the "package" variable receives the file stream properly.

Comment: what's exactly the problem?

Comment: The variable "package" is not getting the file's value, not sure why.

Comment: since you say it is related to particular file, have you tried open it using local file? that is easier to debug. and if still reproduce, maybe you can share that problomatic file for investigating.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "opening it using local file"?

Comment: create a c# console app, read the excel file from local file system first. then experiment with web upload streams.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your Memory stream to position 0 before doing anything else with it.

```
var fileStream = new MemoryStream(fileModel.FileData);
fileStream.Position = 0;
```